How to obtain private key from BIP-39 mnemonic
Trying to obtain a lost private key from 24 mnemonic phrases and a 25th word. Has anybody successfully managed to do this ? Have looked at BIP39 converter but not sure if this has that ability, and seems to return 128 character key and the wallet requires a 64 hexadecimel input


seems to return 128 character key

That could be the seed number not the key.
As BIP-39 says

This seed can be later used to generate deterministic wallets using BIP-0032 or similar methods.

I think you need to apply BIP-32 to the seed, using a suitable derivation path.

